# how to get list of browser installed in a system using python?

Tags: python, selenium, browser

I would like to write a script (in python) which scans the machine.(assumption is system has Linux) and retrieve the list of browser's installed. Looking for suggestions to implement it. I am using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to open links
`browser = webdriver.Firefox()`
Here we have to mention Firefox to open link in Firefox browser. What if user don't have Firefox in machine (chrome installed)?
I had already searched but haven't got any result.

P.S: If system has windows/Mac OS

Answer (score 2):

A better approach: use try/except block

```py
try:
    browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
    browser.get('url')

except (IOException, Exception):
    pass
```

It will help in cases where driver is not able to find the browser or there is some problem while launching.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan all .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` looking for `WebBrowser` in `Categories` field.

Comment: What if we want to check this in mac/windows

Comment: on mac scan `/Applications` folder for well-known names